# How to make Capacitive Touchscreen hold click instead of release click?

Tags: click, touch, mouse, touchscreen

I have a new capacitive touchscreen that when you put your finger in a single spot and hold it there...nothing happens.

When you release your finger a "Mouse Button Down" action and "Mouse Button Up" action occur simultaneously.

I need to invoke a "button down" action while I hold my finger there and a "button up" action when I release.

And ideas?

Comment: Hello, I'm assuming the experts here will ask you to provide more details, but my initial impression is whatever software layer you are working with is to blame. Having a little knowledge about capacitive allows me to state that the screen works in the same manner that you are describing, but that your software (or i suppose hardware poorly crafted not passing through the screen's state properly) is not capturing the screen's state in the way you want

Comment: Note: The screen recognizes your finger when you touch the screen, even without moving your finger around

Comment: What framework, OS, hardware, etc. are present?